# FIDO2 MAKE_CREDENTIAL response issue

Tags: android, android-authenticator, webauthn, safetynet, fido

I am developing FIDO2 Android authenticator. I just received MAKE_CREDENTIAL request from webauthn client. And then

1. Created Credential Data which includes AAGUID, credential length, credentialId,Public key.
2. Public key will contain curve name, algorithm name, key type, x and y coordinates.
3. Then I formed Auth Data which includes rpIdHash, flags, signCount and attested Credential data.
4. Then I sent all those data to webauthn client chuck by chunk in MSG,LLEN,HLEN,DATA format.

   {
       "fmt": "android-safetynet",
       "authData": "9569088f1ecee….”,
       "attStmt": {
           "ver": "14366019",
           "response": "65794a68624763…”
       }
   }

I am using Android SafetyNet attestation in above format. But I didn’t get any response from webauthn server. I am using ANDROID_ID (Manufacture ID) as AAGUID.  Is it correct?

I analysed and debugged my code. I couldn’t able to find any issues. Please help me to proceed the flow.

Comment: what do you mean by webauthn server, is that FIDO2 server ?

Comment: I meant webauthn (webauthn.io) server.